# dell inspiron n4050 vga driver

Tags: dell, intel-graphics, vga

I'm using ubuntu 11.10 . I don't have vga driver installed for it. Where from I can get it?

Laptop: Dell Inspiron n4050

It has Intel HD Grphics card.

Answer (score 1):

Intel Grpahics drivers are included in the kernel . You don't need to add any new drivers for it.

(to confirm you have only Intel grphics you can run `lspci | grep VGA`)

Comment: Yeah, hit that command in Terminal and please tell us the output.